# Indy 10 Broadcast and AData

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm trying to make a text chat through indy udp component and here is the codes for server and client

udp Client:

```
procedure TForm1.SendClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
sendtocl.Broadcast(usertype.Text, 12000);
usertype.Clear;
end;
```

onread Server :

```
procedure TForm1.UDPReceiverUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  AudioDataSize: Integer;
  AudioData : Pointer;
begin
  try
    EnterCriticalSection(Section);
    try
      AudioDataSize := Length(AData);
      if AudioDataSize > 10 then
      begin
        try
          if not Player.Active then
          begin
            Player.Active := True;
            Player.WaitForStart;
          end;
        except
        end;
        if BlockAlign > 1 then Dec(AudioDataSize, AudioDataSize mod BlockAlign);
        AudioData := AudioBuffer.BeginUpdate(AudioDataSize);
        try
          BytesToRaw(AData, AudioData^, AudioDataSize);
        finally
          AudioBuffer.EndUpdate;
        end;
      end else
      begin
        Player.Active := False;
        Player.WaitForStop;
      end;
    finally
      LeaveCriticalSection(Section);
    end;
  except
  end;
begin
chatboxmsg.Lines.Add(BytesToString(AData));
  end;
end;
```

its working good but i had problem if i use the udp client with other purpose like send buffer "To send audio " the `chatboxmsg.line` shows flooded data of audio buffer any way to make the server read separated  `Adata` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To indicate that your problem is solved, please select the answer that solves your problem. If you found another solution on your own, then post that solution in the answer section, and then select it. Do not delete the meat of your question; it makes existing answers look like nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UDP, every send (`Broadcast()`, `Send()`, `SendBuffer()`, etc) transmits a distinct datagram.  The `OnUDPRead` event is triggered for every datagram that is received.  `AData` contains the data of one distinct datagram at a time.

So, you have two choices:

1. format your datagrams in such a way (such as putting a header at the front of the data) so that they identify the type of data they carry.  That way, your `OnUDPRead` handler can read the identifier/header and know whether to put the remaining data to `ChatBoxMsg` or pass it to the sound system.
2. if you do not want to (or cannot) change your datagram formats, then you will have to send text and audio datagrams to different ports.  You can use a single `TIdUDPServer` object listening on multiple ports at the same time (that is what its `Bindings` collection is for), in which case the `ABinding` parameter of the `OnUDPServer` event will tell you which port `AData` was received on.  Or, just use two separate `TIdUDPServer` objects, each one listening on a different port, and assign different `OnUDPRead` handlers to each one.